# Using WhatsApp messaging to notify users when their order is ready

Tags: notification, messages

I'm designing a food ordering experience for a restaurant and we're considering using WhatsApp Business as a way to notify users when their food is ready. this means users will input their phone number at the cart screen of the app. Has anyone here used WhatsApp Business version and could recommend if this is good way or if there are better methods to notify the user when their food is ready? E.g. push notifications?

Comment: +1 to SMS possibly even look at an automated call to inform of the status.

Answer (score 1):

So, I believe in this use case, you don't have mobile app and thus wants to try whatsapp. Why don't you check option for sms? SMS doesn't need internet connection. Also whatsapp makes sense if you want to hear back from
customer like a chat window...